# "<Language> StackOverflow" Twitter accounts

Tags: discussion

There are many Twitter accounts that are language-specific for Stack Overflow, here are some:

- [CppStack](https://twitter.com/CppStack)
- [PythonStack](https://twitter.com/PythonStack)
- [JSStack](https://twitter.com/JSStack)
- [StackJava](https://twitter.com/StackJava)

[image]

Are they official accounts that are ran by the Stack Overflow team? I'm just curios to know.

Comment: Considering they're spelling "Stack Overflow" wrong, I doubt they are official...

Comment: Considering they're using an old logo, I doubt they are official

Comment: Yeah, and the "JavaScript SO" image is extremely ugly.